# Is there species of mushrooms that grow in the wild in Mediterranean environment?

Tags: mycology, environment, agriculture

I'm looking for species of mushrooms which can grow wild (or with minimal human intervention) in Mediterranean environment (which is characterized by dry summers and mild, wet winters.), specifically in north and south Israel (I guess there are different kinds that are adequate to each area) and can spread over significant areas (in a scale of tens of kilometers)

Are there any known species that answer those characteristics? where can I read more about them, their abundance, and how to grow them? I found a-lot of unreliable information, and I'm looking for material with stronger scientific foundation.

Thank you.

Comment: Mediterranean is rather big: it includes the southern coast of Europe, Levant, and North Africa. E.g., [this link](http://israelphilately.org.il/en/catalog/articles/724/Mushrooms) claims 400 species known in Israel.

Comment: double posted https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/22951/are-there-species-of-mushrooms-that-grow-in-the-wild-in-mediterranean-environmen

Comment: By spread do you mean that the "single" fungus spreads its mycelia that far or that it is capable of spreading via sporulation?